# Adding Clicked as a bindable callback property to a custom Xamarin.Forms control?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Below is how I'm defining the property, it works for other types of property like `string` or `bool` but it won't work for the type `Command`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Clicked),
    typeof(Command),
    typeof(MyCustomControl),
    default(Command),
    BindingMode.OneWay,
    propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {
        var control = bindable as MyCustomControl;
        if (!control.GestureRecognizers.Contains(gesture))
        {
            control.GestureRecognizers.Add(gesture);
        }
    }
);
public Command Clicked
{
    get { return (Command)GetValue(ClickedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ClickedProperty, value); }
}
```

I tried searching for how it's done for the class `Xamarin.Forms.Button` but it seems to use the [`IButtonController`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController/) interface which is not for public use.

---

**Update**

I changed the property to `event` type, now the accessors are called when I bind the property from a XAML form, but neither `propertyChanged` nor `propertyChanging` is called.

```
public event EventHandler Clicked
{
    add
    {
        lock (gesture)
        {
            gesture.Tapped += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (gesture)
        {
            gesture.Tapped -= value;
        }
    }
}
```